# Netbeans 8.1 bookmarks are not saved

Tags: netbeans

I create some code bookmarks and they appear in the Bookmark window and can be used to navigate.  However when I restart the IDE they have disappeared.

I'm using netbeans 8.1 on Windows 7. Running it as Administrator.

To reproduce:

1. Open a java project in Netbeans and add one or more bookmarks (CTRL SHIFT M) to java files.
2. Bookmarks are displayed in Bookmark window and can be used to navigate quickly to the relevant code location.
3. Close Netbeans, wait 30 seconds.
4. Start Netbeans and open the same project.
5. The bookmarks window is now empty.
6. Click the bookmark refresh button, still no bookmarks.
7. Change the bookmark view from Tree to View (or vice versa), still no bookmarks.

I raised this as a bug on the Netbeans bugzilla weeks ago but have had zero response.

Comment: Same issue here on xubuntu 16.04 with netbeans 8.1

Comment: can you please provide the link to the bugzilla?

Comment: https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=258162

Answer (score 1):

I have noticed that if you quit netbeans normally (file->exit or clicking the close window icon), it will save the bookmarks.  It will not if it is killed any other way (for example hangup signal.)  You know you have quit it normally if/when you see the very short duration progress bar while it is quitting.)